# AS3 Matrix Rotation

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a string file by utilizing flash.geom.matrix but I'm clueless.  How do you essentially input data into a matrix? I know that you can input data into a, b, tx, ty, etc. but these affect skewing, enlarging, and other stuff.  I simply just want to create a M X N matrix with some data that can be rotated.
Any help?

Comment: Are you sure you want this class ? Just so you know this is not a math class but a geometric utility class for manipulating bitmaps and movieclips

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually going to be using mx.geom now - it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to find a general purpose matrix utility library. The `flash.geom.Matrix` class is only good for representing one specific kind of matrix - that is, a 3x3 matrix representing an affine transformation. That's why you can't change the matrix's size, and that's why it has methods to perform rotations and so on, but no methods for obvious things like finding the determinant.

Unfortunately AS3 doesn't have any standard matrix libraries for general use. Whenever I've needed such things in the past I've just whipped them up by hand, so I can't recommend any good libraries. But here's [a likely-looking project](http://code.google.com/p/as3-matrix-library/) on Google Code that you might try out, and there are apt to be others floating about.